# how to display selected value from list view into the gridview in android?

Tags: android

i have 4 tab keys on my screen ...  1) home 2) favorite 3)hotkeys 4)setting ,,   now the 3rd tab Hotkeys is containing list view of about 20 items with checkbox ,,  and user can select maximum 9 items of that . ..  and those selected item should be displayed  in Grid View in the 1st tab view key that is home. .

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear - What exactly are you trying to do, what have you tried and what problem can't you solve?

Comment: i ve tried to make you clear .... hope u can solve that now